# Matplotlib, draw on top

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am drawing an errorbar plot of some data points, and alongside these points, I want to draw the average in-between two values a line, I also want the line to be drawn on top of the errorbar.

In my code, I write the `pyplot.errorbar(...)` to draw the data points first, and then `pyplot.plot(...)` to draw the lines, and the result is that the errorbar is plotted on top of the lines, such that the line is hardly visible:

[image: The orange line is hard to see]

I have no idea as to how to draw the line on top, this is likely really easy to do, but I do not know how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally controlled using the `zorder` https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html

```
pyplot.plot([0,1], [0,1], linewidth=10)
pyplot.errorbar([0.5], [0.5], 0.3, 0.3, linewidth=20, zorder=-100)
```

[image]

```
pyplot.plot([0,1], [0,1], linewidth=10)
pyplot.errorbar([0.5], [0.5], 0.3, 0.3, linewidth=20, zorder=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also play with transparency (or opacity) by setting the parameter `alpha` in `plt.errorbar()` and the errorbar linewidth (`elinewidth`) to get a desirable effect.

### Example with Dummy Data

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # 'svg', 'retina'
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

# dummy data
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
y, yerr = 2*np.random.randn(x.size) + 5, 1*np.random.randn(x.size)
xerr = 0.2*np.random.randn(x.size)

# make figure
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(16,6))
plt.sca(ax1)
plt.plot(x,y, 'bo', markersize=3)
plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, 
            ecolor='red', elinewidth=1.2, barsabove=False, 
            alpha=0.3, lw=1)
plt.title('elinewidth = 1.2')
plt.sca(ax2)
plt.plot(x,y, 'bo', markersize=3)
plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, 
            ecolor='red', elinewidth=2.0, barsabove=False, 
            alpha=0.3, lw=1)
plt.title('elinewidth = 2.0')
plt.suptitle('Controlling Errorbar Width and Transparency')
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]